# Codes for ImageViewPickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

Tags: iphone

My problem is that i want to replace the camera view with my own view that will capture the image and then again get the same controls of iPhone camera after capturing the image ie.

'Retake' and 'use' will appear.

please reply me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cameraOverlayView to replace your UI and set showsCameraControls to NO to not use Apple's buttons.